# BigQuery table app_events_yyyyddmm loss field resettable_device_id/user_dim.device_info.resettable_device_id

Tags: google-bigquery

I transfer data from Firebase to BigQuery, some days ago, my table "app_events_yyyyddmm" has field "user_dim.device_info.resettable_device_id", but now it is gone.
[image]
Does any know why is that? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with just select count()... from table; ? Just to discard filtering. Can you give more details? like a screenshot of what should be

Comment: Firebase change to new schema so I can't reproduce it.